# Remove time from ASP MVC @Html.TextBoxFor Control using jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker

How do I prevent the time from showing up when using the jQuery `.datepicker()`? Below is the section of the model for the two attributes (date taken and expiration date)

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    [DisplayName("Expiration Date")]
    public string ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    [DisplayName("Date Taken")]
    public string DateTaken { get; set; }
```

This works fine using the `@Html.EditorFor` control on the view I'm working on. However, when I change that control from this:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTaken)
```

to this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTaken, new { id = "dtkn" })
```

in order to get this to work (label which control has the `datepicker` applied to it):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dtkn").datepicker('setDate');
        $("#exp").datepicker('setDate');
    });

    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: '<%=Url.Content("~/Content/images/magnify.gif") %>',
        defaultDate: -1,
        gotoCurrent: true,
        prevText: "<< Prev",
        nextText: "Next >>"
    });
</script>
```

suddenly the time begins to show up. Any suggestions?

EDIT

I have tried the following formats and none will work:

```
$("#dtkn").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
$("#dtkn").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
$("#dtkn").datepicker('getDate').format('yyyyMMdd');
```

and this:

```
$("#dtkn").datepicker('getDate').datepicker('dd/mm/yy');
$('#dtkn').datepicker('option', { dateFormat: 'd MM y' });
```

Here is the error I'm seeing the Chrome debugging console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'datepicker' of null
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Comment: Tried those solutions without any luck. See edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `@Html.TextBox` as opposed to `@Html.TextBoxFor` I was able to find an overload that works.

```
@Html.TextBox("DateTaken", Model.DateTaken.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new { id = "dtkn" })
```

Answer (score 15):

Edit: MVC4 users can use this

You want this overload

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTaken, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { id="dtkn" })
```

If you're willing to give up on the helper just to it manually

```
<input type="text" value="@Model.DateTaken.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")" id="dtkn" />
```

Comment: I get the error `No overload for method 'TextBoxFor' takes 3 arguments`

Comment: Sorry, missed MVC3. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972536/html-textboxfor-formatting-or-html-editorfor-htmlattributes

Comment: this seems to be the most sensitive approach if you don't want to mess with existing markup and/or view model

Answer (score 0):

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTaken,"{0:d/M/yyyy}", new { id = "dtkn" })

[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d/M/yyy}")]
[DisplayName("Date Taken")]
public string DateTaken { get; set; `}`