# Getting jQuery DatePicker to work in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I know this is common problem in the forums and I've read many pages, but still cannot get it to work so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am building an MVC 5 application but I need to support IE9 which is primary Browser for end users. Therefore I can assume HTML 5 support.

From readings it would seem the most common option for non-HTML5 DatePicker is to use jQuery.

What I've done to get this working:

Added to _Layouts.cshtml file:

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

In my view file I have added:

```
<div>
    <div id="datepicker"></div>
    <script>
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    </script>
</div>
```

which works fine and shows a datepicker object.

However, I am trying to associate this to my model's FromDate property so I've tried:
(borrowed from [Remove time from ASP MVC @Html.TextBoxFor Control using jQuery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707982/remove-time-from-asp-mvc-html-textboxfor-control-using-jquery-datepicker))

```
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Start date
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        </script>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBox("StartDate", "", new { @class = "datepicker" } ))
        </div>
    </div>
```

But it does not show a datepicker pop-up object - in IE11 or Chrome on my dev PC.

Any suggestions please?

Regards
Craig

Comment: So this has nothing to do with IE9 at all, then. You said the datepicker works in IE9, and that your code associating it *doesn't* work in IE11 or Chrome (or, presumably, IE9). It's best not to focus people's attention on something that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change your script from

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

to

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

The first selector is looking for an element with the ID of "datepicker" whereas you are interested in elements with the datepicker class.

You should also wrap your script in a document ready handler to ensure that the DOM is ready to rock. See [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for info.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I believe he'll also have to move that script tag to **after** the `div`, as the script runs immediately, and so the element(s) won't exist yet.

Comment: Hi & thanks for your comments.

I changed so View now includes:
        <div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                Start date
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBox("StartDate", "", new { @class = "datepicker" }))
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                (".datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        </script>

IE gives error:
"Line: 117
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'".
Line 117 is: (".datepicker").datepicker();

Craig

Comment: @JamieDunstan: *"You should also wrap your script in a document ready handler..."* Best practice is just to put the scripts at the end of `</body>`, you only need `ready` if you don't control where the scripts go.

Comment: @CraigRoberts: Just look at that line for a moment. What's missing from the front of it? Hint: Right now you're trying to call `.datepicker` on a string.

Comment: I missed the $ in front of (".datepicker").datepicker.