# Using EditorFor with templateFormat and a Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to rewrite this piece of code using the solution presented here: [Html.TextBoxFor formatting or Html.EditorFor htmlAttributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6210209/196210)

```
<div class="input">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
    @MyFunc()
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
</div>
<br />
```

But, since the call to this template format has no parameters, how can I pass the lambda expression `x => x.Name` to `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`?

I have this parameter on the calling page and I need to send it to the EditorFor template page:

**Calling page**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
```

**Classical example EditorFor template page**

```
@model System.DateTime? 
@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty, new { @class = "date-picker" })
```

**Real example of EditorFor for this case???**

```
<div class="input">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(????????)
    @MyFunc()
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(??????)
</div>
<br />
```

Comment: which version of mvc are you using?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateModified)` and  have an `EditorTemplate` include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`? In which case `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)` or `@Html.ValidationMessage("")`

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain me in a better way it?

Comment: When you use EditorFor you can instruct him to use a specific template through the instruction UIHint. In this template I would like to put the code: @Html.ValidationMessageFor(...); can I achieve that objective?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: yes. I've also clarified the question.

Comment: @Revious, Either one of the 2 options I included above will work (and you will might want to include `@Html.Label("")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: thanks! (if you answer I can accept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Html.ValidationMessage("")` or `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)`. For example

```
<div class="input">
    @Html.Label("")
    @Html.TextBox("")
    @Html.ValidationMessage("")
</div>
```